# Convert list of array to array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I use angular CLI 6 and firebase. I obtain in type script this list of array ;

```
(3) [Array(5), Array(5), Array(5)]
     0 : (5) ["Chimiothérapie", "rettreret", 4, 1534716000000, 1535061600000]
     1 : (5) ["Chimiothérapie", "trferterteretretetr", 3, 1535061600000, 1535320800000]
     2 : (5) ["Chimiothérapie", "zrteretetrertertgerter", 4, 1534370400000, 1534716000000]
     length: 3__proto__ : Array(0)
```

I want to convert the first one to this type of object :

```
(3) [Ppsplan, Ppsplan, Ppsplan]
 0 : Ppsplan {typetraitement: "Chimiothérapie", acte: "rettreret", duree: 4, datedebut: 1534802400000, datefin: 1535148000000}
 1 : Ppsplan {typetraitement: "Chimiothérapie", acte: "trferterteretretetr", duree: "", datedebut: 1534111200000, datefin: 1534111200000}
 2 : Ppsplan {typetraitement: "Chimiothérapie", acte: "zrteretetrertertgerter", duree: 3, datedebut: 1535493600000, datefin: 1535493600000}
length :3
 __proto__ :Array(0)
```

I try this :

```
this.ppssToDisplay2 = this.ppssService.getSinglePPS2(this.key);
this.ppssToDisplay2.subscribe((ppsList: PPS[]) => {
    console.log(ppsList);

    let data =[];

    ppsList.map((pps: PPS) => {
        Object.keys(pps.ppsplan)
            .forEach(key => {
                let ppsplan: Ppsplan = pps.ppsplan[key];
                data.push([ ...interestingFields.map(field => ppsplan[field]) ]);

                const convert_data= (list: any[]) => new Ppsplan(...list);
                let ppsplans = [];
                for (let list of data) {
                    ppsplans.push(convert_data(list));
                }
            });

        console.log(this.ppsplans);
    });
});
```

ERROR : expect 3 - 5 argument but got 0

Ppsplan in my interface :

```
export class Ppsplan {
  constructor(public typetraitement:string, public acte:string, public duree:number, public datedebut = new Date() , public datefin = new Date() ) {}
}
```

Comment: What have you tried and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: i update, thkss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let list_of_list = [
    ["Chimiothérapie", "rettreret", 4, 1534716000000, 1535061600000],
    ["Chimiothérapie", "trferterteretretetr", 3, 1535061600000, 1535320800000],
    ["Chimiothérapie", "zrteretetrertertgerter", 4, 1534370400000, 1534716000000],
];

export class Ppsplan {
    constructor(
        public typetraitement: string,
        public acte: string,
        public duree: number,
        public datedebut = new Date() ,
        public datefin = new Date()
    ) {}
}

const convert_list_to_object = (list: any[]) => new Ppsplan(...list);

let list_of_objects = [];
for (let list of list_of_list) {
    list_of_objects.push(convert_list_to_object(list));
}

console.log(list_of_objects);
```

Comment: @KaiserKatze you could use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `new Ppsplan(...list)` instead of `list[0], list[1], ... etc`.

Comment: @alNTM What do you mean by "You can't change directly your tscode"?

Comment: @KaiserKatze Existing an another way than my subscribe method (in my question)?

Comment: @alNTM I think the problematic part in your code is this: `data.push([ ...interestingFields.map(field => ppsplan[field]) ]);`. @see [Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). Without knowing what `interestingFields`, I can only guess that you should have written like this: `data.push( ...interestingFields.map(field => ppsplan[field]) );`. Please note that I remove the pair of brackets around `...interestingFields.map(field => ppsplan[field])`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use map

```
let list_of_list = [
    ["Chimiothérapie", "rettreret", 4, 1534716000000, 1535061600000],
    ["Chimiothérapie", "trferterteretretetr", 3, 1535061600000, 1535320800000],
    ["Chimiothérapie", "zrteretetrertertgerter", 4, 1534370400000, 1534716000000],
];

mylist=list_of_list.map(x=>{
   let obj={
       typetraitement: x[0], 
       acte: x[1],
       duree: x[2],
       datedebut:x[3],
       datefin:x[4]
   }
   return obj
})
```